# MIXed click. function event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Somehow the both click events being mixed up.

After I click 6 times on different `<div id="tit_` alert will pop 6 times, but
when I click once on `$("#EX")` - alert of the EX div will pop 6 times! This is not the only one where
both events are being mixed up;
why? How to fix it?

```
 function Cream(Cresults) {
             var div = $('<div/>');
             $.each(Cresults, function () {
                 $('<div id="tit_' + this.Cream_Id + '">' + this.Cream_Id
                 +'</div>').click(function () {
                                               alert("you clicked on the first div");
                                              }).appendTo(div);
                                              $('<br/>').appendTo(div);


 $("#EX").click(function () {
 alert("that is the second div");
                             });

                                               });             

 $("#Grid").html(div);
 $("#Grid").append(div);
 }

        <div id="EX">X</div>
```

The loop prints div for each cream - if there are 200 creams there will be 200 divs: tit_1...tit_200 the second alert actually needs to use the id so that is the reason it is in the loop.

Comment: Can you add your HTML layout - or even better create your example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ - I suspect the events are bubbling - have a read of the [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method in jQuery

Comment: Any chance you could edit your question so indentation / readability is a bit better?

Comment: alert("8975").stopPropagation(); ? i cannot jsfiddle because all the functions being called by server:(

Answer (score 1):

It seems you imply that `Cresults` contains 6 items. In that case, you're indeed adding 6 click handlers (i.e. 6 alerts when clicked) to `#Ex`. Using `.click` does *not* remove the previous function that you added, but adds the new function so that you can bind several functions to e.g. `.click`. You'll see this more clearly if you indent a little bit better:

```
function Cream(Cresults) {
    var div = $('<div/>');

    $.each(Cresults, function () {
        $('<div>').attr("id", "tit_" + this.Cream_Id)
                  .text(this.Cream_Id)
                  .click(function () {
            alert("you clicked on the first div");
        }).appendTo(div);

        $('<br/>').appendTo(div);

        $("#EX").click(function () { // apparent inside the loop, so added 6 times
            alert("that is the second div")
        });

    });             

     $("#Grid").empty().append(div);
 }
```

You should move the `.click` outside the loop to make it only alert one time.

I changed some other things as well: setting both `.html` and appending does not make much sense. You probably want to empty `#Grid` first like this:

```
$("#Grid").empty().append(div);
```

And you can write the `#tit_` divs a little cleaner like:

```
$('<div>').attr("id", "tit_" + this.Cream_Id)
          .text(this.Cream_Id)
          .click(function () {
    alert("you clicked on the first div");
}).appendTo(div);
```

Comment: the loop prints div for each cream - if there are 200 creams there will be 200 divs: tit_1...tit_200  the second alert extualy needs to use the id so that is the reason it is in the loop

Comment: @Sveta23: In that case you're indeed binding one click event per `#tit_` div, but also binding 200 click events to `#Ex` which means 200 alerts will pop up when clicking `#Ex`.

Comment: so what are my options?:( the alerts are exctualy calls to functions...i can put the second call inside the first function...would it be the right move?

Comment: @Sveta23: So the `#Ex` click needs to use each ID from `Cresults`? I'm not sure if you do or do not want 200 alerts - you want `#Ex` to use each ID but you do not want to run the function 200 times?

Comment: the alerts are actually calls to functions...i can put the second call inside the first function...would it be the right move?

Comment: @Sveta23: Do those functions need to be called 200 times when clicking `#Ex`? What are those functions actually doing?

Comment: the first alert is a call to function that prints cream info - imagen 200 rows of cream info. i need that when user will click on a row it would pop alert with the id of the cream...

Comment: @Sveta23: Then I don't see a reason for the alerts on `#Ex`. The first alert call would be sufficient as I understand it.

Comment: the problem is that when i put it inside the function it still pops same number of times as i click on the tit_ div